# Как вывести все товары из выбранной категории на странице?

Tags: php, html, sql, mvc, pdo

возникла проблема с выводом товаров из категорий( в выпадающем меню), категории отображаются, но не знаю,как правильно сделать так, чтобы в sql запрос подставлялся  id при выборе нужной категории и выводились соответствующие ей товары(пытаюсь делать по паттерну MVC).

Запрос для категорий CategoryModel.php

```
class CategoryModel extends Model {


public  static function Get_Category (){
    $conn=DB::connToDB();
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM categories");
    $result = array();
    $stmt ->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[$row['id']]=$row['name'];
    }

    return $result;

}
}
```

Запрос для товаров ProductModel.php

```
 class ProductModel extends Model
  {
  public function products($idcat)
  {


    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, name,price,description  FROM 
    products WHERE category_id = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$idcat]);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
}
```

ProductController.php

```
 require_once (MODEL_PATH ."/CategoryModel.php");
 class ProductController extends Controller
 {
private $pageTpl = "/Views/templates/product.tpl.php";
   public function __construct()
  {
    $this->model=new ProductModel();
    $this->view= new View();
   }
    public function index(){
    $this->pageData['title']="Украшения";

    $category=CategoryModel::Get_Category();
    $this->pageData['category'] = $category;

    $idcat=$category['id'];
    $this->pageData['products']=$this->model->products($idcat);
    $this->view->render($this->pageTpl,$this->pageData);
    }
}
```

И на всякий кусок обрабатывающий категории:

```
  <div class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
  <?php foreach ($pageData['category'] as $key =>$value): ?>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href = "/product?<?= $key?>" >
  <?=$pageData['category'][$key]?></a >

     <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div >
```

Comment: А как в методе `index` вы получаете значение категории которая передается?

Comment: Решила проблему с помощью $id_cat= $_GET['idcat'];   в контроллере )